# URL works with trailing slash, returns a 406 without it

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat

I have an API that if I send my request to it works perfectly if I include a trailing slash but returns a 406 if I remove that slash.

The request:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/app/pay.pl?action=actionhere&email=my@email.com&password=password&amount=1&currency=USD&bnf_email=recipient@domain.com&subject=subject&note=note&frn_trn_id=111
```

This doesn't work and returns a 406, but if I add one character:

```
http://localhost:8080/project/app/pay.pl/?...
```

With the trailing slash after the 'pl' it works.

Now this is running in tomcat 9, using Spring 4.3, and Java 8.

The Config:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(true);
    }

    ...
}
```

And the Rest controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/app/{pay:.+}"}, method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = {"application/xml;charset=UTF-8"})
public Object handle(...) {
    ...
}
```

If I just make it "/app/pay.pl" it returns a 400